# prevent background with size=cover from moving when the window is resized

Tags: css

I have a background with background-size: cover on a web page.  Is there a way to prevent the image from moving when the window is resized? or is this just a limitation of how cover displays the wallpaper?

Is there another way to achieve the same result using a different method?

Essentially I need to have a fixed wallpaper that covers the entire screen, and needs to handle smartphones and desktops.  The background is also not an abstract image, and has an off-center "subject" that I would like to highlight when on mobile using background-position coordinates.

Any help is appreciated.

*EDIT:*

Thanks for the help, folks.  I think the problem isn't possible within the constraints of background-size: cover, and will take some creative CSS on my end.  I wanted to field some answers to see if there was a more "expected" way to do this, but it looks like I'm out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

this happens because that's how `background-size:cover` works

**background-size:cover**

> Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image. Some parts of the background image may not be in view within the background positioning area

without an example code from you, i can only  suggest you use `background-size:contain` instead

**background-size:contain**

> Scale the image to the largest size such that both its width and its height can fit inside the content area

see more here [background-size](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

let me know if it helps

Comment: The problem I have is that contain doesn't scale well between desktop and mobile.  Most wallpapers are 16:9, which work fine on desktop, but end up repeating vertically, and 4:3 mobile wallpaper has the opposite problem.

The specific problem I'm having is that on a mobile device, when the software keyboard opens, my wallpaper moves because the vertical height of the container changes.  I think I'm just going to have to use a fixed position wallpaper that as sufficiently large on mobile and use media queries to handle everything.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the containing element of said `background-image` is tall enough to scroll, you can use `background-attachment:fixed;` or `background-position:fixed`.

The following Snippet demonstrates a fixed background using `background-position:fixed`. In order to cover the viewport entirely, I used: `background-size: contain` and `background-repeat:repeat`. `background-size:cover is also effective as long as you don't mind that the image might get cropped.

#### SNIPPET

```css
body {
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png)repeat fixed;
  background-position: fixed;
  background-size: contain;
}
.content {
  width: 200px;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

```html
<section class='content'>
  <p>Mauris a nunc occideritis me rectum. Videtur quod Ive facillimum, qui fecit vos. Potes me interficere, sine testibus et tunc manere in pauci weeks vel mensis vestigia Isai Pinkman et vos quoque illum occidere. Exercitium inutili option A. Videtur mihi
    quod autem est.</p>

  <p>Pergo coctione, et ego, et tu oblivisci Pinkman. Obliviscendum hoc unquam factum. Intelligamus hoc in sola SINGULTO multo aliter atque fructuosa negotium structura. Malo B. Option.</p>

  <p>Ille vivere. Ut ad te quaerebam ... purgare caeli. Sunt uh ... nonnullus propter errorem qui de rebus inter nos et iacere puto suus in causa, id est in mensa. Levir meus, priusquam oppugnarent tempus quis, admonere dicitur. Credo quod idem mihi praesidium.</p>

  <p>Suspicio? Bene ... tunc ibimus? Quis uh ... CONEXUS locus his diebus? Quisque semper aliquid videtur, in volutpat mauris. Nolo enim dicere. Vobis neque ab aliis. Ego feci memetipsum explicans. Gus mortuus est. Lorem opus habeo.</p>

  <p>Jackson Isai? Tu quoque ... A te quidem a ante. Vos scitis quod blinking res Ive 'been vocans super vos? Et conteram illud, et conteram hoc. Maledicant druggie excors. Iam hoc tu facere conatus sum ad te in omni tempore?</p>

  <p>Ludum mutavit. Verbum est ex. Et ... sunt occidat. Videtur quod est super omne oppidum. Quis transfretavit tu iratus es contudit cranium cum dolor apparatus. Qui curis! Modo nobis certamen est, qui non credunt at.</p>

  <p>Nonne vides quid sit? Tu es ... Jesse me respice. Tu ... blowfish sunt. A blowfish! Cogitare. Statura pusillus, nec sapientium panem, nec artificum. Sed predators facile prædam blowfish secretum telum non se habet. Non ille? Quid faciam blowfish, Isai.
    Blowfish quid faciat? In blowfish inflat, purus?</p>

  <p>Blowfish librantur in se quatuor, quinquies maior quam normalis, et quare? Quare id faciam? Ut terrorem facit, qui quid. Terrent! Ut alter, scarier pisces agminis off. Et quod tu es? Vos blowfish. Tu iustus in omnibus visio. Vides ... suus ' suus 'non
    aliud aerem. Nunc ... qui cum partibus blowfish Isai? Tu damnare ius. Vos blowfish. Dicere iterum. Dicere illam quasi velis eam. Es BLOWFISH!</p>
</section>
```

Comment: unfourtunately I'm looking to use a wide aspect-ratio image that I don't want to repeat.  My required scenario seems too narrow to not have to put in some extra work to get it done.  I think I'm just going to have to use media queries and get creative between mobile and desktop.